# Сессионные переменные и нагрузка на сервер

Tags: php, сессия

Слышал, что в работе скриптов сайта нужно использовать как можно меньше сессионных переменных. Сейчас у меня задействовано 4 таких переменных. Буду добавлять еще. Есть ли конкретные ограничения на размер $_SESSION[] при проектировании ресурса с предполагаемой большой посещаемостью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да просто не надо их на диске хранить.

Comment: Ну, любая сессионная переменная пишется на диск. Не так ли?

Comment: Мы переложили их в редис. Время жизни 10 минут. При каждой инициализации скрипта время начала отсчета смещается. Все очень просто.

Comment: Где можно быстро ознакомиться с этим вот "редисом"?

Comment: Мы все сами писали, а если погуглить то есть уже все готовое )
http://habrahabr.ru/post/169241/

Comment: тут есть небольшой момент, независимо от того redis у вас или что, массив $_SESSION[] будет грузиться после session_start(). и если там данных на гиг... то при каждом запуске, даже если вам в конкретный запуск эти данные не нужны, они будут залазить в память.

Comment: @eicto, приветы вам! Я ничего не знаю про работу серверов, однако, я понимаю, что $_SESSION[] УЖЕ  записывается на диск, пока сессия продолжается... Вы можете мне подсказать, сколько сессионных переменных я могу инициализировать?

Comment: @dimka3210, спасибо вам за все готовое!

Comment: @Deus ограничений особо нет, дело в производительности,